# Как выглядит плохой код под паттерн "Фабричный метод"?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Я изучаю паттерны и столкнулся с проблемой что не могу найти плохой код, который можно было бы переписать с использованием паттерна "[Фабричный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))".

В учебных материалах найденных в гугле приводят либо абстрактные примеры, либо плохие примеры где безосновательно используется паттерн "фабричный метод".

Как я могу найти пример плохого кода, который бы явно нуждался в паттерне "Фабричный метод".

Я пытаюсь найти пример с обоснованием почему в этом примере необходимо использовать фабричный метод и почему без него будет плохо.

Comment: т.е. такой пример https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Creational/FactoryMethod/README.html или https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/factory-method вам не понравился?

Comment: Именно, нужен случай когда без паттерна не обойтись. В refactoring guru очень хороший абстрактный пример, но плохого кода к этому примеру нет, только картинки. А в  designpatternsphp не очевидный случай использования фабрики, в логгере можно обойтись и просто условным оператором, это ни на на что не повлияет.

Comment: *"не могу найти плохой код"* - разве [код на php бывает хорошим](https://www.programming-idioms.org/idiom/149/rescue-the-princess/1838/php)?

Answer (score -1):

Фабричный метод стоит использовать *не потому* что без него не обойтись если нужно лишь чтобы программа в принципе работала, а потому что с его помощью можно уменьшить [связанность программы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), отделив создание объектов от их использования. Также не имеет смысла рассматривать практическое использование фабричного метода отдельно от других паттернов, таких как, например, [внедрение зависимостей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Например, если за создание объекта отвечает фабрика, то объекту-пользователю во время тестирования можно [через DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) подсунуть [подставной Mock-объект](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82), дальше используя [паттерн Spy](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Spy.html) для проверки количества и качества вызываемых объектом-пользователем методов. Если вы не пользуетесь фабрикой, а отдаёте создание объектов самим пользователям, то вам будет очень сложно или невозможно провести такое глубокое юнит-тестирование. Без этого паттерна скорее всего вам придётся ограничиться интеграционным тестированием.

Иначе говоря, фабричный метод и родственные паттерны стоит использовать *на практике* не столько потому, что без них никак нельзя, а сколько потому что с ними программа будет лучше и глубже протестирована, а значит вы будете спать лучше и ваш CI скорей найдёт ошибки, которые иначе можно пропустить.